# Strange response from Rails API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, cross-domain, httparty

I have a middleware Rails app that calls a remote server API call, also in Rails. This call has been working up until the last couple days, as far as I can tell. The middleware server is new, we moved this service over the weekend.

The remote calls basically go like this:

Mobile App => Middleware Rails app => remote server Rails API

The mobile app successfully makes 2 calls down to the remote server. The 3rd call has started to receive this response

```
{
"date": [
    "Mon, 24 Jun 2019 21:03:44 GMT"
],
"server": [
    "Apache/2.x.x (Red Hat)"
],
"x-frame-options": [
    "SAMEORIGIN"
],
"x-xss-protection": [
    "1; mode=block"
],
"x-content-type-options": [
    "nosniff"
],
"etag": [
    "\"641c2178771ebfb98623a7ce302384cb\""
],
"cache-control": [
    "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"
],
"x-request-id": [
    "94365150-2c68-4f10-86cd-cf33f8d2e43e"
],
"x-runtime": [
    "0.222738"
],
"x-powered-by": [
    "Phusion Passenger x.x.x"
],
"status": [
    "200 OK"
],
"vary": [
    "Accept-Encoding"
],
"content-length": [
    "421"
],
"connection": [
    "close"
],
"content-type": [
    "application/json; charset=utf-8"
]
```

}

I've logged that at the middleware level, so it's happening between the middleware and the remote server. The middleware is using HTTParty to make the HTTP Post call. This was working up until this weekend possibly.

I'm at a loss as to what is returning this. I see the call making it down into the API on the remote server. The server/network admins say they haven't added/changed anything that would flag that. Anyone have any ideas on where to even begin to look?

**Edit:** the middleware server is a Ubuntu 18.04 system. I'm running Apache with Passenger for the Rails app. UFW is setup. The remote server is a RedHat server running Apache and Passenger as well. In case that might help.

Comment: This question as written is too broad and basically unanswerable. There’s an unbounded set of possible causes. But there’s not enough information in the question for anybody here to narrow it down to anything more specific. So all that anybody else here could do at this point is just speculate among the possible causes.

Comment: Have you tried calling the endpoint directly with Postmen or any other client capable of triggering REST requests for instance?

Comment: i realize it's quite broad. I just don't even know where to start with this.